# Is C.GoBytes required to retrieve a C buffer, or is a pointer sufficient here?

Tags: c, go, cgo

The cgo code below has a function to put a Go value in a C buffer, and two alternative functions to get it back; getViaGoBytes and getDirect.

Is getViaGoBytes any better than getDirect?

I assume not, and the intermediary slice created in getViaGoBytes is unnecessary.

Am I correct in thinking Go allocates enough memory when the uint64 y variable is declared, and the assignment to y copies the memory from C to Go?

```
package main
/*
char buf[8];

void put(char * input, int size) {
    while (size--) {
        buf[size] = input[size];
    }
}
*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func put(input uint64) {
    C.put((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&input)), C.int(unsafe.Sizeof(input)))
}

func getViaGoBytes() uint64 {
    var out uint64
    data := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(&(C.buf[0])), C.int(unsafe.Sizeof(out)))
    out = *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))
    return out
}

func getDirect() uint64 {
    return *(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&(C.buf[0])))
}

func main() {
    var input uint64 = 1<<64 - 1
    println(input)
    put(input)
    var x uint64 = getViaGoBytes()
    println(x)
    var y uint64 = getDirect()
    println(y)
}
```

Comment: Even if you are only shifting 1 by 63 bits, in C `uint64_t n = 1<<63;` will not work when `int` is 32 bits, it would need to be `uint64_t n = (uint64_t)1<<63;`, and secondly shifting out 64 bits will leave you with `0` anyway. Would this apply to Go, especially the second point?

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane, I didn't know cast is required in C! In Go, 1<<64 - 1 is (1<<64) - 1 according to [operator precedence](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators). The layout, forced by [gofmt](https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code), tries to imply the precedence. Regarding the second point, constants can be very large in Go, as long as they fit into a type on assignment. [1 << 400, for example](https://play.golang.org/p/nA_NfBJycS). See also [constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions). When the code above is run, it writes 18446744073709551615 three times.

Comment: GoBytes copies a C allocated buffer into a slice with Go allocated memory. If that's what you want, then use GoBytes. Here you're not even keeping that copy, so there's no reason to do it.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, you've answered the question, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking question answered by copying JimB's answer from comment:

> GoBytes copies a C allocated buffer into a slice with Go allocated
>   memory. If that's what you want, then use GoBytes. Here you're not
>   even keeping that copy, so there's no reason to do it.

Also, benchmark is interesting:

```
$ go test -bench . -benchmem
BenchmarkGoBytes-8      20000000            97.8 ns/op        32 B/op          3 allocs/op
BenchmarkDirect-8       2000000000           0.84 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
```